# Как лучше хранить данные о существовании записей с данной категорией?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Как лучше хранить данные о существовании записей с данной категорией?
Есть многоуровневые категории и задача: нужны те, у которых есть записи, причем если у подкатегории есть записи, то у родителя тоже как бы есть записи.
Как организовать такое?
Сделать в БД отдельное поле и менять его, когда изменяется категория у какой-либо записи?
Или делать это динамически, при загрузке создавать массив? Если категорий будет много, то сильно ли повлияет на быстродействие в отношении оперативной памяти?

Comment: Ммм. "Динамическое" хранение данных... Это вообще как?

Comment: Ну мол собрать массив существующих категорий и потом проверять есть ли категория в этом массиве. Но если будет очень много записей, сильно ли это замедлит процесс и много памяти будет съедаться?

Comment: В реляционной БД в одной таблице хранится категория, в другой - записи. Объединяются таблицы по индексу. Если у записи несколько категорий и их кол-во неизвестно заранее, то лучше сделать промежуточную таблицу, где у каждой записи будут указаны существующие категории (естественно индексы)

Comment: Вы уж совсем за идиота не держите меня :)
Есть список категорий, и у некоторых могут быть записи, а у некоторых нет. Мне нужны только те, где есть записи. Причем категории многоуровневые и хочу сделать так, чтобы если у подкатегории есть записи, то и у всех родителей как бы есть записи.

Comment: *"многоуровневые"* -- это существенная деталь. Также можно поподробней раскрыть что "лучше" слово означает: дублирование данных, быстродействие на каких запросах итд. Подобные вещи лучше в вопрос добавить вместо комментария.

Comment: @MrGaliev "Мне нужны только те, где есть записи" - Всё зависит от того стыкуете вы записи к категориями или категории к записям (почитайте про LEFT, INNER, RIGHT JOIN). Так же при поиске записей вам ничего не мешает в условии включить Категорию и всех её потомков. Обрисуйте вашу задачу конктретнее, если вы, конечно, сами знаете чего хотите

Comment: А если завести дополнительную табличку - связь между родительскими и дочерними категориями? Т.е. если у категории 1 есть подкатегория 2, а у нее подкатегория 3, то в табличке будут связи `(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)`. Тогда по этой табличке мы получим все категории если у одной из дочерних есть запись.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не занимайтесь преждевременной оптимизацией. Сначала создайте нормализованную базу данных, в которой нет избыточной информации. Если замеры производительности покажут, что запросы с вашими критериями происходят слишком долго, а узкое место — необходимость склеивать таблицы, то можете "испортить" нормализацию и добавить поле с кэшированным значением числа записей в категории.

Ничто не даётся бесплатно. Если вы будете кэшировать значение, то у вас возрастёт сложность кода, появится риск рассинхронизации кэшированного значения с актуальным значением. Если же вы не будете кэшировать, то у вас будет гарантированная консистентность данных, но более медленные запросы.

Если количество записей и категорий в пределах тысяч, а запросы не слишком частые, то вы не почувствуете проблем со скоростью. Если у вы планируете миллионы записей и категорий, и тысячи запросов в секунду, то производительность будет для вас критична. Если вы не знаете реальный масштаб, то сделайте просто, а при необходимости усложняйте.

Comment: У заказчика большие планы :)
А пока действительно, сделаю попроще.